# Find the directional derivative in $(x,y)=(0,0),\vec{u}=(1,-1)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ a differntiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Find the directional derivative in $(x,y)=(0,0),\vec{u}=(1,-1)$.

Using $\nabla_uf=\nabla f\cdot \frac{u}{\|u\|}=(f_x,f_y)\cdot \frac{(1,-1)}{\sqrt{2}}$.

How to use the fact that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for solving this problem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since the function is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, $f_x=f_y$

$(f_x,f_y)\cdot \frac{(1,-1)}{\sqrt{2}}= \frac{f_x-f_y}{\sqrt{2}}=\cdots$

Comment: I forgot it implies $f_x=f_y $ is the directional derivative is $0$?

Comment: @Algo precisely